# Plotly iplot() doesnt run within a function

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter

I am trying to use iplot() within a function within Jupyter so that i can use a filter on the graph and have it change dynamically. The code works in a cell on its own like this

```
 # Code for put by ticker
 data = []
 opPriceDic = priceToArray(getPuts(getOptionPricesByTicker('ABBV')))
 for key, values in opPriceDic.items():
    trace = go.Scatter(
       x = numberOfDays,
       y = values,
       name = 'option',
       line = dict(
           width = 4)
       )
       data.append(trace)
# Edit the layout
layout = dict(title = 'Call prices for ' ,
          xaxis = dict(title = 'Days to Expiration'),
          yaxis = dict(title = 'Price '),
          )
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='calls For ')
```

But once this is placed within a function the graph fails to load

```
def graph(ticker):    
# Code for put by ticker
data = []
opPriceDic = priceToArray(getPuts(getOptionPricesByTicker(ticker)))
for key, values in opPriceDic.items():
    trace = go.Scatter(
        x = numberOfDays,
        y = values,
        name = 'option',
        line = dict(
            width = 4)
    )
    data.append(trace)
# Edit the layout
layout = dict(title = 'Call prices for ' ,
              xaxis = dict(title = 'Days to Expiration'),
              yaxis = dict(title = 'Price '),
              )
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='calls For ')
```

But if I change the iplot() to plot() it calls the plotly API and opens a new tab with the graph displaying.

I am just wondering if anyone has noticed this before and may have come across a solution?

(if I am in the wrong area I will remove the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to use pandas [data.reader](http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html) calls to pull ticker data between a start and end date. The `data.reader` seems to work from within the function. In the question code, if the `opPriceDic` dictionary could be converted to a dataframe, then `iplot()` could plot it without use of layout and fig as below:

```
# Import libraries
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()


# Create function that uses data.reader and iplot()
def graph(ticker):
    # create sample data set
    start = datetime.datetime(2006, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
    df = data.DataReader(ticker, 'morningstar', start, end)
        df = df.reset_index() 
        df['numberOfDays'] = df.apply(lambda x: abs((datetime.datetime.now() - x['Date']).days), axis=1)

# call iplot within the function graph()
df.iplot(kind='line', x='numberOfDays', y='Close', xTitle='Days', yTitle='Value', title='Prices', width=4)
```

[image: Line plot using iplot() from within a function]